# How do I enable my application to write in home/**user**/.config?

Tags: command-line, sudo, sublime-text

I recently downloaded Sublime Text and when I entered the license into it.
It replies

> Unable to write license file: /home/scaffrey/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/License.sublime_license

and then every time I type `subl` in the terminal,it tells me I'm unregistered.

However,if I type `sudo subl` , things go in the right way.

So my question is , how to enable sublime text to write its license?
It's annoying because sometimes I forgot to type sudo and the changes I made turned out lost.
I've set up a post in the forum for sublime text,but no one has replied yet.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: You should have write permissions in your current user's home directory. Check it with `ll /home/scaffrey/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/License.sublime_license` or if that does not exist yet, `ll -d /home/scaffrey/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/`. It will show you the rights on either your license file or the directory where it should be. [Edit] your message and post the output of those two commands. Then we see what we have to change.

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks.the first one replies `Permission denied`,and the second one tells me that it belongs to root:`drwx------ 2 root root 4096  6月 16 19:37 /home/scaffrey/.config/sublime-text-3/Local//`.sorry for the delay,I just don't have a consistent network with BCM43142...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not good that this directory inside your home directory is owned by root.

Did you maybe run any configuration scripts etc. as root?

Anyway, please execute:

```
sudo chown -R scaffrey:scaffrey /home/scaffrey/.config/sublime-text-3/
```

That should return the ownership of all files and directories below and including this one back to your user.

And please don't forget: *Never mess around with normal graphical programs with `sudo`. At least use `gksudo`, if it is really necessary, but try to avoid it anyway!*

Comment: its working now! really thanks a lot!I've learned a lot:)

Comment: No problem. I am happy to help! :-)